# XY coords to XZ positive/negative coords like minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

I recently came up with the idea to color my minecraft map with a picture of colors. So this is how I created a picture with different colors in paint, then in my plugin - each color means a different block I made forums that take each color from XY and save it to the map key - (Point object with X and Y variables) and as a color value but I encountered a problem - blocks are generated only in one corner because the points in the picture are only positive and the Minecraft map consists of positive and negative coordinates. Now I have a question, does anyone have any idea to change these points to positive and negative, for example I have a 51x51 px picture so for x: 0 z: 0 there must be a color from the point x: 26 z: 26 etc. Thank you for any help I have tried everything, sometimes it seems to me that I had a good idea and it will be a breakthrough, but after a while one big XD comes out of it

Comment: subtract 26 from coordinate

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i did understand you wrong, but you have the problem that the blocks are placed on wrong positions if you try to put the converted image on a position with negative x or z value?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make a separate coord system that you come up with

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm sorry, when i have time i will edit this this was just a scrap thing i didn't put much thought into